# How to configure ant pattern in jenkins for email attachments?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am trying to give the following ant pattern for attachments.

I believe my base directory could be /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/

I have  error.log.gz file in directory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/error/

The email is coming with no attachments. Can some one please tell where its going wrong, or could you please share a sample ant xml pattern for attachments in jenkins?

Comment: Usually base directory for a job is: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<name_of_job>/workspace. Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern-

```html
<attachments>
  <fileset dir="dist">
    <include name="**/*.gz" />
  </fileset>
</attachments>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have tried using the above pattern in attachments field, it didn't work.
Also I have tried changing the base directory as /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<name_of_job>/ there is no folder called workspace inside the specific job folder by default.
Please let me know if anybody has tried this attachments in their projects!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below pattern in Editable Email Notification,it will send the attachment in email

```
**/error/error.log.gz
```